# Differences of elements of a set of natural numbers (reference request)

Tags: co.combinatorics

Let $A$ be a subset of $[n] = \{1,2,\dots,n\}$.

Define $\overline A = \{(i,j) : i, j \in A \text{ and } i > j \}$ and define $(i_1,j_1) \sim (i_2,j_2) $ if $i_1 - j_1 = i_2 - j_2$.

This is clearly an equivalence relation and I want to understand the cardinality of the equivalence classes. I am counting some combinatorial objects in my research problem and for this reason, I need these numbers.

Any literature or thought regarding these cardinalities is appreciated.

PS: Let $C_k$ be the cycle graph and in each of its vertices attach degree one vertices as many as one wants. The resulting graph is called crab and the cycle we start with is called as the spine of the crab. This graph has equal number of vertices and edges.

If we delete two edges on the spine, the graph is separated into two trees. We label the edges $1$ to $n$ clockwise and we see that the labeling on the edges of the cycle defines the crab uniquely. If we delete the edges $i$ and $j$  with ($i > j$) of the cycle then there are two trees with $i-j$ and $n-(i-j)$ number of vertices. I want to know how many such partitions $(i-j, n-(i-j))$ are possible given the labeling $A \subset [n]$ of the edges on the cycle.

This is the background of the problem.

Comment: I would appreciate it if you give more information about the background of the problem. Little can ne deduced from the informatin you have given.

Comment: The equivalence classes correspond naturally to the positive elements of the difference set $D=A-A$. The set $D$ is symmetric around $0$ and its size can be anything between $2|A|-1$ (when $A$ is an arithmetic progression) and $|A|(|A|-1)+1$ (when $A$ is a Sidon set).

Comment: @Seva Thank you. do you know any finer result then upper and lower bounds?

Comment: There are lots of results around; try to google for "popular differences", "Freiman's theorem", "Freiman's (3n-3)-theorem" or check any monograph on additive combinatorics (Nathanson, Tao-Vu, Grynkiewicz). Exactly what kind of result do you need?

Comment: Thank you. I want non trivial bounds in the size of the equivalence classes. Plz let me know if you some results.